Indent title for lightning-tile
<lightning-tile label="ABC"> </lightning-tile>
How to indent the title of this lightning-tile without using something like a <div> around it ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I don't think this is possible OOTB. You can try using slds styling with html markup. More info - https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/tiles/
